# Why is BAWSAQ still under maintenance?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I can purchase stocks at LCN website but the BAWSAQ is still under maintenance, I've completed 45% of the game and can't buy stocks from that website. Am I missing something? Do I need a special mission to unlock it?

Comment: From what I understand, BAWSAQ is basically influenced by the collective GTA V online community and how they play/what stocks they buy/sell on BAWSAQ. I'm sure someone can explain this in greater detail. Could be ready when the online mode will be released.

Comment: You can access it whenever. You just need to be signed into the online network for whichever console you're using.

Comment: @Foo A lot of the times in game though, it will come up with "BAQSAQ is down for maintenance, please try again later." messages, even when signed into XBL/PSN.

Comment: You can access it through the Social Club website. You also can't buy or sell there, but watching rates is possible already.

Comment: It was under maintenance yesterday, but not any longer. Maybe the 13+ million gamers are putting BAWSAQ under heavy load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BAWSAQ is influenced by the online community and it's likely down due to server loads. Games as popular as GTA V almost always have connectivity issues the first week or two after release so it's probably related to server load issues. Rockstar is also aware of the issues with BAWSAQ and [you can check this article for updates it's current status](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200357093).

Once it is is back up, if you need any help with the stock market here's [a guide I found useful](http://geekfed.com/grand-theft-auto-5-stock-market-tips/323).

Answer (score 2):

You have to sign into the rockstarclub for the BAWSAQ to work. That's it

Answer (score 0):

I'm only providing what I know, but I've had the BAWSAQ available since the start, I've even purchased shares in it already (in preparation for online becoming available). I don't even think I'd linked up by Rockstar Social account by that point but maybe I had. So long story short, I think it should work for you just maybe you keep catching it on a down time. I know I haven't been able to get SnapChat working because it was having problems, same with flight school leaderboards.